# Is it possible to cache the response of a Server to Server HTTP POST request?

Tags: rest, web-services, http, service, request

The purpose is to not trigger the request more than once at n days (for financial reasons) - the HTTP client should look into the cache to determine whether the response is already available. Will the max-age directive set to n days in the response help (e.g. Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800)?
I know this is available for GET requests with an enableCaching(ttl) option, but can we achieve similar behavior for POST requests?

To resume, my only idea is that if the response comes with an n day max-age directive set, this would force the service which makes the request to make another call after n days, no matter if it's a GET or POST.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Redis](https://redis.io/) is that what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can request that POST responses get cached, but there are no promises. From [RFC 7231][1]:

> Responses to POST requests are only cacheable when they include
> explicit freshness information (see Section 4.2.1 of [RFC7234]).
> However, POST caching is not widely implemented.

If you control both the server an the client, you can:

> For cases where an
> origin server wishes the client to be able to cache the result of a
> POST in a way that can be reused by a later GET, the origin server
> MAY send a 200 (OK) response containing the result and a
> Content-Location header field that has the same value as the POST's
> effective request URI (Section 3.1.4.2).

Also, note that any cache could clear out your representation at any time, so just because you ask for something to stay cached doesn't mean it will. You're specifying a *max* age, not a *guaranteed* age.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3